# FinancialData no longer fetches historical prices?

Tags: curated-data, finance

Starting sometime after May 12, 2017, Historical Data from FinancialData seems to have stopped working. Has anyone else seen this?  Here is some input:

```
$Version
Date[]
FinancialData["GE"]
FinancialData["GE", "May 19, 2017"]
FinancialData["GE", "May 12, 2017"]
```

and the corresponding output:

```
11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)
{2017,5,20,12,52,19.298469}
28.05
Missing[NotAvailable]
Missing[NotAvailable]
```

Comment: Same output for `11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)`.

Comment: I have noticed the same thing. I have found the same values with calling WolframAlpha and getting the values from pods

Comment: There seems to be a problem with their servers. I reported it to customer service, and here is their answer: "A report has been made on the issue regarding FinancialData and you will be informed when it gets resolved. The problem seems to be related to some issues with Yahoo's servers, where the data comes from. They let us know, that their engineers are working on a fix. Unfortunately we have little control over the matter, but hopefully, they will be able to resolve it sooner rather than later."

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'm trying to deal with it in the meantime. @Diogo is right as Yahoo has gone down before b/c it's also affecting python pandas. But I can't remember it previously affecting Mathematica. Following @FredrikD & just calling WolframAlpha but still working to update the rest of the script as data must be formatted differently.

```
data = WolframAlpha["AAPL close Jan 2 2017 to May 19 2017",{{"DateRangeSpecified:Close:FinancialData",1},"FormattedData"}]
Print[data]
```