# FinancialData -- Yahoo problem or Wolfram problem?

Tags: finance

Last May, problems surfaced with FinancialData (see [FinancialData no longer fetches historical prices?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146503/financialdata-no-longer-fetches-historical-prices)). This week, FinancialData ignores mutual fund prices for the last day of May, although WolframAlpha *does* find such data.

Don't *FinancialData* and *WolframAlpha* both use Yahoo as the data source? If so, why does only one return data for May 30? To me, this behavior suggests the fault lies with *Mathematica* rather than *Yahoo*.

Fails:

```
FinancialData["VFINX", {"Jun 29, 2017", "Jun 29, 2017"}]
FinancialData["VFINX", {"Jun 30, 2017", "Jun 30, 2017"}]
FinancialData["VFINX", {"Jul 3, 2017", "Jul 3, 2017"}]
```

Succeeds:

```
WolframAlpha["VFINX close Jun 29 2017 to Jul 3 2017",
{{"DateRangeSpecified:Close:FinancialData", 1}, "FormattedData"}]
```

Comment: As of v13.1 neither of those options work